# Differentiate between an API and GUI call in Laravel

Tags: laravel, api

I'm new to Laravel and still exploring.

Is there a way to differentiate if calls made to an API is from a REST client like Postman or from GUI?

I earlier did something like this which worked -

```
if ($request->is('api/*'))
```

but later I had to remove the "api" prefix from the URL and so now I have no way of differentiating the calls.

The URL to call my api - http://localhost/myprojectname/someAPI

What I'm trying to achieve is return a custom error in Authenticate.php middleware if call is made from API.

My earlier code

```
protected function redirectTo($request)
{
    if ($request->is('api/*')) {
       //return custom message
    }
    
    if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
        return route('login');
    }
}
```

but now that the "api" prefix is removed from URL, I'm not sure how to differentiate.

Comment: You might consider using `$request->expectsJson()`, depending on what "from GUI" entails.

Comment: It's not clear what you're trying to achieve here

Comment: @ceejayoz, the thing is the API can return any accept type, like xml, csv, json etc. and so I won't be able to rely on the expectsJson(). From GUI means if a request is made from an UI application or an API. Example, in Authenticate.php middleware, there's the default code 
        if (! $request->expectsJson()) {
            return route('login');
        }
I want to return a custom message if the call is made from API, so I did
        if ($request->is('api/*')) {
           //do something
        } 
but now the "api" prefix is removed from the URL and so I can't use my old code

Comment: @apokryfos, I'm trying to understand if there's a way to differentiate if a call to an API is made from a RESTful API client like Postman/cmd prompt using curl etc. or from GUI application. I have edited the question to explain it better.

Comment: Typically the user agent tells you who requested it. Granted it can be spoofed but if you need this information to provide a better user experience then someone spoofing it is not really a problem. You can probably use https://github.com/jenssegers/agent or something similar to determine if the request is coming from a GUI or not

Answer (score 1):

You could differentiate between them by calling the `request()->header()` method.
It determines the `user-agent` that sent the request is it postman or any other browser.
Another useful things that it returns the `accept` parameter that determine the way the sender want to receive the result, for example when you send this request from an HTTP client like `axios` it returns `application/json` which means it a REST client that expect to receive the result as a json response. While the GUI browser returns `*/*` which means it's prepared to receive any kind of response.

Note: by default the postman client returns `*/*`

Comment: Thank you, Rateb. The $request->header() is a good suggestion. I'll try that. I won't be able to rely on the accept parameter though because my API accepts any kind of return format like xml, csv, json etc.